# How to apply this regex?

Tags: regex, json

sorry for this question, but I've already spent 6 hours trying to apply one regex.
When parsing one social network, I faced problem: some nicknames can contain double quotes (f.ex. `John "Superstar" Smith`), and my app fails when trying to jsonfy these strings. Here're errors that I see from online validator:
[image]
**So, how can I replace 2x Double quotes to 1x Double quotes where the previous word is `"nickname":`?**

I tried grouping (?="nickname":) and looking for 2x double quotes (\"\") but with no luck.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you saying that an API you don't control is returning invalid JSON (unescaped strings) such that you are unable to convert it into an object? Or are you actually trying to manipulate JSON with regex _instead of_ just parsing it?

Comment: @Mathletics, Sorry, Engligh is not my native language, so I may be misunderstanding you. That API returns me 2x double quotes 'cause the person's nickname has it. To proceed further, I need to jsonfy that code, which I can't do without replacing 2x double quotes to 1x double quotes
----
When I'm trying to jsonfy that output in python, it fails with `Expecting ',' delimiter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
"{2}([^,}]+?)"{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oL5ffFqwEVVWYFGE)

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I've just found one new solution and another one was proposed from another website (just to save it in history):
`(?!nickname)""[^\w\s]*""` and
`""\W*""(?=,)`

Comment: `""\W*""(?=,)` won't match - `\W` matches non-word characters and `(?=,)` will only match trailing commas, and won't match if nickname is the last property of the object as it will be followed by `}`. Could change it to `(?=[,}])` though.

Comment: yes, you're right. However, this worked specially for my situation, because Python didn't recognize cyrillic letters (he found them as \W). Thanks again!

Comment: `(?!nickname)""[^\w\s]*""` - won't match any non-word characters e.g. `'` or `-` and haven't got a clue why there's a negative lookahead at the beginning of the regular expression.

Comment: `why there's a negative lookahead`
because I need to find a string, which goes AFTER "nickname" word

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82332/discussion-between-phuzi-and-kondra007).